# How to run linux command from php

Tags: php, c++, c, linux, command

I want to compile a c/c++ code in linux server. I am using php. Suppose I am receving a source code from user and then I am making a temporary file with it and then using gcc I am just trying to make a simple executable. To do all those I am doing the following code but it is not producing any output. So how to run a linux command from php in linux server , I mean is the following code ok. if yes then why it is not producing any executable named "latest"

```
$received_code = $_POST['myc'];


        $fp = fopen("myfile", "w") or die("Couldn't open file for writing!");
        fwrite($fp, $received_code) or die("Couldn't write values to file! ...Compilation Error");
        fclose($fp);

                shell_exec("gcc -o latest myfile");
```

Comment: What does `$result = shell_exec("gcc -o latest myfile"); var_dump($result);` write?

Answer (score 1):

I think a good guess is that `gcc` isn't in your PHP PATH, but just getting the output from your `shell_exec` call would probably tell you that:

```
$output = shell_exec('gcc -o latest myfile');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

Try using an absolute path to gcc

Answer (score 1):

At least, rename myfile to myfile.c, or gcc won't recognize it as c source code.

Did you check if myfile gets written? If not, it might be a permission problem.

By the way, have fun with malicious users if you think of executing their program after compiling it :-)